# How to acces class-properties via index[]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, properties, indexing

I've got a static class with some list of other classes which have properties of different Types. for example:

```
public static class MainClass
{
    public static List<ClassA> List1 {get;set;}
    public static List<ClassB> List2 {get;set;}
}

public class ClassA
{
    public string a;
    public int i;
}
public class ClassB
{
    public string c;
    public int j;
    public Image icon;
}
```

what i'd like to do now, is accessing the properties via index:
(after adding imaginarily 5 instances to List2)

```
Image picture = MainClass[1][4][2]; //getting a value from Mainclass.List2[4].Image
MainClas[1][1][1] = 42;             //setting a new value to Mainclass.List2[1].i
```

what do i need to do for archieving this goal?

atm i try to acces List1 & List2 by adding this into my Class:

```
public static object[] loop = new object[2] {List1, List2};
```

but wenn i try to index loop, its not working...

Comment: Why would `MainClass[1]` correspond to `List2` particularly? Why would `2` correspond to the image? This sounds like it would rapidly lead to unreadable code.

Comment: if MainClass is indexable and i use 1, the second property in MainClass (which is List<ClassB> List2 is addressed. In ClassB the third property is Image icon, which would be adressed via 2

Comment: @MauricioGracia: There is no such thing as a *"this[int pos] extension method"*. This is an indexer.

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink: The order of the members of a class is unspecified and meaningless, so your whole construct is very fragile. Furthermore, as Jon points out, your code will be totally unreadable. In short: *Very bad idea*. Maybe you could explain what problem you are trying to solve with this approach?